# if 30 out of 3500 drivers had an accident last year, what percent of the drivers had an accident

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If 30 out of 3500 drivers had an accident last year, what percent of the drivers had an accident (round to the nearest tenth of percent)? plzz help me with this problem if you can and I will be thankful.

Answer (score 4):

You know that the *fraction* of drivers who had an accident last year is $\dfrac{30}{3500}=\dfrac3{350}$. This means that $3$ drivers out of every $350$ had an accident last year. The *percentage* is the number of drivers out of $100$ who had an accident last year. If we call this number $p$, we want $p$ to satisfy the equation

$$\frac3{350}=\frac{p}{100}\;.$$

Multiplying both sides by $100$, we see that $$p=100\cdot\frac3{350}=\frac{300}{350}=\frac67\approx0.857\;,$$

or $0.9$% to the nearest tenth of a percent.

The same reasoning, carried out in general, shows that to convert any fraction whatsoever to the corresponding percentage, you just multiply by $100$.

Comment: @user87132: You’re very welcome.